# use a tuple {Char, Array{Char,2}} as a key in a dictionary for Julia

Tags: dictionary, julia

Is there a way to use a tuple of {Char, Array{Char,2}} as a key for a dictionary?

```
plays = Dict()
player = 'w'
state = Array{Char}(9,9)

...

count = get(plays,(player,state),-1)
```

Comment: i guess you've already found the answer `plays = Dict( (player,state) => 1 )`

Comment: yea you are right. I had a bug in my code so I thought the syntax was incorrect. Thanks for the help!